# Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 connection drops infinite times

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I have a laptop with a **Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]**.

Here is the adapter information:

```
stan@pho:~/Downloads$ lspci | grep -i net
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Yukon Optima 88E8059 [PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Controller with AVB] (rev 11)
```

The adapter gets connected, an it gets immediately disconnected. And that is repeated infinite times.

The output of `dmesg | egrep 'wlan0|iwl'` show the following lines multiple times:

```
[ 1752.722768] wlan0: authenticate with 20:aa:4b:cb:40:94
[ 1752.743331] wlan0: send auth to 20:aa:4b:cb:40:94 (try 1/3)
[ 1752.750735] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1752.754666] wlan0: associate with 20:aa:4b:cb:40:94 (try 1/3)
[ 1752.758641] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 20:aa:4b:cb:40:94 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[ 1752.763976] wlan0: associated
[ 1801.420240] wlan0: deauthenticating from 20:aa:4b:cb:40:94 by local choice (reason=3)
```

It seems the most common solution is to disable the N mode from the wireless card, so I tried this:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwldvm
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

But it is still not working.

**UPDATE:**

I can confirm that the issue is related to the Wireless N mode. If I go to the admin page of my router and configure it to only use Wireless B/G mode, then my computer can keep a connection with the router.

[image]

So, I guess there is something wrong with the commands I typed to disable N mode in the wires adapter of my computer.

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command will turn N speed off for your device permanently but not in your router:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwldvm
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

The commands you ran in your question to disable N speed are only temporary they are lost when you reboot.